# LINQ to XML. Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm having trouble populating an object from an XML file.  I've copied an example I've found almost exactly, with variable names changed, but I keep getting the "Enumeration yielded no results" exception.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim element As XElement = XElement.Load(path)

    Dim itemProps = From p In element...<Property> _
                Where p.<LanguageCode>.Value = "en_us" _
                Select p.<Title>.Value, p.<Description>.Value
```

**Using breakpoints, I have confirmed that the 'element' variable is being properly populated using the XElement.Load(path) method.**

Here is the XML file that is being accessed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Items>
  <Item ItemID="1">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="1">
      <Title>Title1</Title>
      <Description>Description1</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemID="2">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="2">
      <Title>Title2</Title>
      <Description>Description2</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemID="3">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="3">
      <Title>Title3</Title>
      <Description>Description3</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemID="4">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="4">
      <Title>Title4</Title>
      <Description>Description4</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemID="5">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="5">
      <Title>Title5</Title>
      <Description>Description5</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
  <Item ItemID="6">
    <Property ItemPropertyID="6">
      <Title>Title6</Title>
      <Description>Description6</Description>
      <LanguageCode>en-us</LanguageCode>
    </Property>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Essentially, the XML query is supposed to return the title and the description for every Property which has an element called Language Code, which is equal to "en-us".  I have a feeling that my problem lies in my XML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This language code:

```
en_us
```

should be:

```
en-us
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking one of the dots out of

```
Dim itemProps = From p In element...<Property>
```

Your going 3 levels down, when you only need to go down 2.

If that doesn't work try just one dot, because essentially the path your travelling is only 1 below the root of the document.

Comment: 1 dot doesn't work, and 2 dots gives me an "Identifier expected" build error.

Comment: I really don't think the number of dots represents levels deep in an XML file, but is simply part of the syntax of LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I was going out on a whim with it if the truth be known, I don't normally do VB so sometimes the syntax throws me off, in C# however nesting level is important, but it's not expressed using multiple .'s but rather multiple nesting of element/elements calls.